# What is the safest way to implement a tree structure?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, tree

I want to create a tree structure in my program. Right now I have something similar to the following:

```
class tree_node
{
    public:
        tree_node (tree_node* parent) : parent_(parent)
        {
            parent_.add_child(this);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<tree_node*> children_;
        tree_node* parent_;
}
```

My main concern with this design is that the `tree_node` class can delete any of its children and the parent. I want to change the design to disallow this. So:

- Can I somehow change the design to use references instead of pointers? (vector of references does not work).
- If I use references, how can I treat the special case of the root node (which has no parent)?
- Can I disallow the deletion of children/parents by the `tree_node` class?

Any other ideas to achieve my goal are welcome.

Comment: Er, and who is going to be managing the memory for the tree, if not the tree itself?

Comment: Is it? Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Have you seen `vector_manager` anywhere in the standard library? Or `map_manager`? No, because it's a completely silly idea. The container is responsible for managing its memory, not some external unrelated class.

Comment: That's not really an argument or an explanation. Why is it a silly idea? What is wrong or not recommended with this approach? You can't find most of, say, boost in the STL either, but that doesn't make boost a silly idea, does it?

Comment: @Dan the thing is, you can find trees in the STL. You can't find `tree_manager`s though. I want a `tree_ceo`.

Comment: Actually, many parts of Boost *are* being incorporated into standard library, but that's beside the point. You can come to Lounge<C++> if you want to discuss sillyness of managers.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes that's not what I meant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: To answer the question asked in the title but not in the text: The safest way is to NOT re-implement a tree. Use a standard library associative container or possibly boost BGL.

You could use a reference wrapper class within containers (and a `boost::optional` holding such a wrapper for the parent reference if desired), but I'm not sure this is a solution to your underlying problem. The `tree_node` class doesn't do any memory management so there isn't a particular risk of deletion.

Next, do you *really* need an N-ary tree? Could you get away with `std::map` or one of the other associative containers and avoid coding up a bunch of bugs?

Obviously your tree's public API shouldn't provide direct access to the node class (check out `map` and its use of iterators), so as long as the tree is properly managing the memory, your worries about pointer management should be minimal because you fully control all management of the nodes.

Answer (score 7):

A safe solution is to store the children as [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) and store the parent as a raw pointer. The root node then has it's parent node set to `null`.

To answer your questions:

> - Can I somehow change the design to use references instead of pointers? (vector of references does not work).

You have to use pointers in this situation. References simply won't work.

> - Can I disallow the deletion of children/parents by the tree_node class?

When designing a tree the most common-sense ownership model would be that nodes have ownership of their children and not vice-versa.

You are saying that you want to disallow a class from doing something to itself. How does that make sense? If you don't want your class to delete its own children then simply don't do it.

Comment: Or `std::unique_ptr` for children and non-owning pointer to parent. You probably need to implement deep copy anyway to avoid Fun.

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't do any memory management and thus it will not delete any other nodes. If you want to make sure that anybody who uses a tree_node class doesn't delete any parents or childeren you need to put those into a pure virtual base class (where they are private) and have tree_node inherit from it. A user who uses tree_node is then forced to use the methods you provide.

Also, if you don't want to worry too much about pointers use smart pointers (see boost::shared_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

I can see why children cannot be allowed to delete a parent node but I don't understand why you would want to disallow deletion of a child. That is one of the most fundamental ops in a tree.